# Post wordpress blog posts to Facebook

Tags: wordpress

I want all the blog posts in a specific category to be posted as status updates on Facebook. Which means: all posts posted in the category named "X" should be posted automatically to my Facbook (fan)page.

Any experience of this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use a plugin, see: http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/ one for example.

#
This plugin automatically publishes posts from your blog to your Social Network accounts such as Facebook, Twitter, Google+(Google Plus), Blogger, Tumblr, LiveJournal, FriendFeed, DreamWidth, Delicious, Diigo, Instapaper, Stumbleupon, LinkedIn, Pinterest, Plurk, VKontakte(VK.com), YouTube, WordPress, etc. The whole process is completely automated
#

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of auto posting from WordPress to social networks (such as Facebook). There are 3rd party services and plugins that you can use to achieve this.

Some may have more configuration options like choosing which categories as you mentioned but others will simply post all new blog posts to the chosen social networks with the ability to pick which networks.

See [How to Auto Post from WordPress to Social Networks](http://tribulant.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-post-from-wordpress-to-social-networks/) for a list of possible solutions. I hope it helps!